# C# run batch file, command not recognised

Tags: c#, file

I have implemeneted a method into my c# program to run a batch file, which runs a virus scan on any files uploaded;

```
public static Int32 ExecuteCommand(String filePath, Int32 Timeout){
    Int32 ExitCode;
    ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    ProcessInfo.FileName = filePath;
    Process proc = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
    proc.WaitForExit(Timeout);
    ExitCode = proc.ExitCode;
    proc.Close();
    return ExitCode;
 }
```

Ok now my batch file;

```
@ECHO OFF
c:
cd "..\AVG\AVG9\"
avgscana.exe /SCAN="..\learninglounge.com.solar.quarantine\" /REPORT="..\learninglounge.com.solar.antivirus\virusReports\report.txt"
```

EDIT : I do have fully qualified link to avg exe and directories but have replaced here with .. for purposes of posting to stackoverflow.  Sorry if this caused confusion.

So my problem is the reporting side of my batch file.  I can double click the batch file and it scans and creates the report no problem.  When i run it through my c# i get an exit code of 2; command not recognised.  It's fine if i remove the report part of my batch file.  Now obviously this points to write permissions but I have checked that and the impersonated user has write access on the directory.  Is there anything Im missing?

Thanks all

Comment: Does avgscana.exe exist in the directory the program is?

Comment: no it doesnt, i remove the file path and replaced with .. from the batch for here, but it is fully qualified in the actual file

Comment: Some off-topic suggestion: Microsoft recommends not to use CLR type names, but use C# specific ones. That would mean Int32 should be declared with "int" instead, and so on :)

Comment: For the sake of debug try hard coding the `exe` file path and the report `txt` file path - if it works it means you need to pass the path to the batch file as process arguments and read it using `%1`.

Comment: please see update, i do have hardcoded paths but for purposes of posting here I have replaced with ... Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: i will eventually be using process arguments to pass in individual files to check but am passing in hardcoded directory for testing.

Comment: Try using environment variables in your script. `SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\...\avg\ `, then you should be able to call avgscana.exe without requiring it's fully qualified path.

Comment: @Mark H yes i can do that but not really helping with my issue as i can run avg scan no problem, its just the writing of the report that does not work in my c#. as a separate batch file it scans and creates report ok.

Comment: You didn't fix your post.  Having the proper directory names is critical, the error you get says they are not.  The Windows error code for "file not found" is 2.

Comment: @Hans I get a command prompt exit code of 2 which is unrecognised command.  If I remove the /REPORT section of my batch file it runs no problem therefore it is finding AVGscana.exe no problem and is scanning the quaratine directory no problem.  I do have proper directory names in my batch file but removed them when posting to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well ive done a work around, id rather have saved the report there and then but instead i just catch the standard output from the process and then save to a file + any processing.

Weird one this.

Answer (score 1):

The error states that `avgscana.exe` isn't located in directory which is set as "current" when you execute command. When you click on your bat file in Windows Explorer current directory is set to directory where bat file is located. Probably your `avgscana.exe` is located in the same folder so it works fine.

When you execute the command from .Net application current directory remains the same (if you haven't changed it then it will be a folder where .Net app is located). If your .Net app is located not in the same folder as bat file then you will get an error which you're actually getting. You should either specify a full path in your bat file or set `Environment.CurrentDirectory` in .Net app before launching bat.

Comment: i will update my question but in my batch file i do fully qualify the link to the avg exe and the folder where i want the report to be saved. I just put .. for purposes of posting on here.

Answer (score 0):

HAve You checked that all enviromental variables are set exactly the same as You run the batch file from cmd line. I am pretty sure that there might be some differences. Also what kind of operating system is it. If this requires elevation (vista windows 7) You might actually need to impersonate appropriate user in code.
luke

Comment: yes i run impersonation and the user has write access on the directory, what sort of environmental varialbes should i be checking?

Answer (score 0):

In your batch file, you have:

```
c:
cd "..\AVG\AVG9\"
avgscana.exe 
  /SCAN="..\learninglounge.com.solar.quarantine\"
  /REPORT="..\learninglounge.com.solar.antivirus\virusReports\report.txt"
```

When the command is executed, the 'current' directory on drive C: is ambiguous. You just move up the directory tree. Same with the avgscana.exe command, you make relative references instead of absolute.

Are you certain that the CD command has brought you to the correct directory? Change the CD command to an absolute reference ( cd "c:\wherever\avg\avg9\" ), and that way you can be sure your avgscana command's relative references are found.

Your CD command may be failing silently but your avgscana.exe may be in your path, so it does get executed, but since the relative /scan and /report locations are not found, it fails with a code 2.

Good luck!

Comment: I think ive already mentioned several times that my paths are all absolute and that they work no problem.  The problem is with the /Report command. I remove it, its fine and i prove this by catching the standard output and receiving the results of the scan.  i put /report back in and it fails with exit code 2.  The batch works fine when clicked in windows but only fails through my c# program.